# modelState.isValid not checking required decorated attributes

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, modelstate

I'm having this issue with `ModelState` validation, since I'm using a model with an attribute decorated with `[Required]` attribute but it never gets invalid, even on `null`.

Here's the controller:

```
[HttpPost("x/{sampleString}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status303SeeOther)]
public IActionResult Post(string sampleString, SponsorContractorFilterModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return StatusCode(BadRequest("Model sent is not valid").StatusCode.GetValueOrDefault());
    //do stuff, add location on header and send back the 303.
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status303SeeOther);
}
```

And the model is pretty simple:

```
public class SponsorContractorFilterModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SponsorContractorFilterModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public SponsorContractorFilterModel()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sponsor number.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public int? AnImportantNumber { get; set; }

    public List<int> SomeIds { get; set; }
     //few more attributes not been decorated on purpose.

}
```

The thing is that when I send with postman a model object without an "AnImportantNumber" or explicitly `null` in neither of the cases it shows that is invalid. And when I debug it I can see its actually mapped as `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `[BindRequired]` attribute to make sure data were present on the request. There is [No source for a model property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#no-source-for-a-model-property) section in the docs that explains a bit.

Also there is a bit older article [[Required] and [BindRequired] in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/12/required-and-bindrequired-in-asp-net-core-mvc/) written by Filip W. about that subject. It may be good starting point/inspiration too.

Hope it helps